# Cross-platform filepaths comparison

Tags: c#, .net, path, mono, cross-platform

I'm trying to check if two file path strings specify the same path.

We know paths are not case-sensitive in Windows.

```
Path.GetFullPath(path1).Equals(Path.GetFullPath(path2), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

I know it will not work correctly on Linux, cause paths **are** case-sensitive there. So I'm searching for some indication of platform case-sensitivity for paths. Or for some function like `Path.Equals`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it's probably the easiest (and most reliable) to check if `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` is equal to '/' or '\' and if it's the former, call the same method without the "IgnoreCase" part.

In full:

```
if(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar == '/')
{
    Path.GetFullPath(path1).Equals(Path.GetFullPath(path2), StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
}
else
{
    Path.GetFullPath(path1).Equals(Path.GetFullPath(path2), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: Hhmmm, it's pretty interesting. Thanks for reply. I hoped for something clear.